I am trying to tune the rotate anchor in konvajs
On this page (https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Scale_Image_To_Fit.html), dragging the rotate anchor causes rotation. I want to change this anchor to an image.
I have already modified the anchor on this page (https://woongjin.swink.co.kr/AIDT/1/MAT/2022/E3/1/5639544/5639614/5639862/5640899/5640899.html) and applied it. Now, I want to change the green circular shape to an image.
